# Wordpress SITE_URL in wp-config.php is not overriding database setting

Tags: wordpress

In order to make my wordpress site easier to deploy I have added the following code to wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

It is my understanding that this should override any values stored in the database, but when I view source I see that wherever I have:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
```

...it is printing out the domain from the database value, rather than the one in wp-config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the content dir for your plugins and themes

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php